# Find element by value simple html dom parser

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I need to find element by existing value, i using simple html dom parser, input html - may be not full.
example
Html:

```
<div class="params">
   <dl class="row param">
      <dt class="param_title">Name</dt>
      <dd class="param_content">Some name</dd>
   </dl>
   <dl class="row param">
      <dt class="param_title">Sum</dt>
      <dd class="param_content">23400</dd>
   </dl>
   <dl class="row param">
      <dt class="param_title">Address</dt>
      <dd class="param_content">Here some address</dd>
   </dl>
</div>
<div class="params">
   <dl class="row param">
      <dt class="param_title">Name</dt>
      <dd class="param_content">Some name</dd>
   </dl>
   <dl class="row param">
      <dt class="param_title">Address</dt>
      <dd class="param_content">Here some address</dd>
   </dl>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
foreach($html->find('dd[class=param_content]') as $el)
  echo $el->innertext . '<hr>';
```

Result:

```
Some name
23400
Here some address
-----------------
Some name
Here some address
```

But this code does not work for me, i need from output text like this:

```
Some name
23400
Here some address
-----------------
Some name
Null<-because there is no Sum, write Null, that's what I'm looking for
Here some address
```

Comment: If there's anyway to get the param_title. Then just handle your logic in that manner.

Comment: That is, we know that sum will follow name. So after we get name, check if title is sum, if so we're good, if not echo null

Comment: You need a library that supports `:contains` to do this he right way.